# On circumcircle, incircle, trillium theorem, power of a point and additional constructions in $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

The problem was at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3699003) deleted question originally.

> Given:
>   1) $\triangle ABC$ -- an arbitrary triangle
>   2) with [circumcircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle) $\omega$ centered at $O$
>   3) and [incenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incenter) $I$.
>   4) Let $D$ be the second intersection $AI$ with $\omega$,
>   5) $P$ be the point of intersection of line $BC$ and the line, perpendicular to $AI$, passing through $I$,
>   6) Let $Q$ be the point, symmetrical of $I$ through $O$.
>
> Prove that $\angle PAQ=\angle PDQ=90^\circ$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer*: this is not in a way my solution, I simply asked a person with strong contest math background to look at the problem, they gave me the solution then. I don't think I can solve geometry problems such a way.
[image]
I) 1) Let the continuation of $OD$ intersects $\omega$ in $D'$.
2) $IO=OQ$ and $DO=OD'=R$ $\Rightarrow$ $DID'Q$ -- parallelogram $\Rightarrow$
3) $D'I||QD$.
[image]
II) 4) Let $X=PD\cap\omega$,
5) let $\angle A=2\alpha$;
6) let $\angle B=2\beta$ $\Rightarrow$
7) $\angle IBC=\beta$ as $CI$ is bisector of $\angle ABC$
8) $ID=DC$ by the [trillium theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trillium_theorem) $\Rightarrow$
9) $\angle CID=90^\circ-\beta$ because
10) $\angle IDC=2\beta$ as an inscribed angle, subtended by the same arc $AC$, as $\angle ABC$ $\Rightarrow$
11) $\angle PIC=\beta$ $\Rightarrow$
12) $\triangle ICP\sim \triangle BIP$ $\Rightarrow$
13) $\displaystyle\frac{IP}{BP}=\frac{CP}{IP}$ $\Rightarrow$
5'-13') And even a faster way: $DC=DI=DB$ by the trillium theorem, so $D$ is center of circle $BIC$, but $IP\perp ID$ and $ID$ being a radius of circle $BIC$ makes $IP$ tangent to circle $BIC$ thus $IP^2=CP\cdot BP$ by the secant-tangent theorem,
14) $IP^2=CP\cdot BP$ -- is the power of point $P$ relative to $\omega$ $\Rightarrow$
15) $IP^2=PX\cdot PD$ $\Rightarrow$
16) $\triangle PXI\sim\triangle PID$ $\Rightarrow$
17) $D',I,X$ are collinear because $DD'$ is a diameter (expanded: $\angle PXI=\angle PID$ from similarity $\Rightarrow$ $\angle DXI$ $=180^\circ-\angle PXI$ $=180^\circ-90^\circ$ $=90^\circ$, but $\angle DXD'$ is subtended by diameter $DD'$ $\Rightarrow$ $\angle DXD'=90^\circ$ $\Rightarrow$ $\angle IXD'$ $=\angle IXD-\angle DXD'=0$)
[image]
III) 18) $D'I||QD$; $\angle D'XP=90^\circ$ $\Rightarrow$
19) $\angle QDP=90^\circ$
20) Center of the circle $QDP$ is the middle of $QP$.
21) $QO=OI$ and if we pass a line through $O$ which is $||IP$,
i.e. perpendicular to $AD$ then it will pass through center of circle
$QDP$ (we can use converse [Thales' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) to see it)
22) but the line is bissector perpendicular of $AD$ $\Rightarrow$
23) $A$ lies on the circle $QDP$ (indeed, the line connecting the centers of two circles and thus containing their diameters is perpendicular to a chord $AD$ of $\omega$ and perpendicular to a chord of circle $QDP$, containing $D$, so the chords are the same) $\Rightarrow$
24) $\angle QAP=180^\circ-\angle QDP=90^\circ$

Comment: *"I don't think I can solve geometry problems such a way."* What do you mean by this? that you don't think the question's author intended this proof's level of sophistication? or perhaps that you don't believe you personally have reached this proof's level of sophistication? (I'll note that this is the first I've seen of the "Trillium Theorem", so we're all always learning!) Something else? In any case, you should add some remarks after the proof about which steps you find problematic. Then perhaps others can either help explain those steps or find less-problematic alternatives.

Comment: Even if we take the first step alone, I see it's a sufficent reduction of the problem as we get rid of inconvenient point $Q$ (indeed there's not many facts we know of this point) in favor of diameter $DD'$. But I don't imagine how do I come to this idea myself. I even can't think am I on the right track or not. All I see looking at the initial picture is that $D$ is in the middle of arc $BC$. And about uncertain points, all the comments in parenthesis are mine, so I see the solution rather clear)

Comment: As @Blue said, first encounter with "Trillian theorem" ? Is it the creation of G. Trillian (from Erivan) or S. Trilli (from Firenze) ?

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie , corrected the header typo